# Wordpress white screen of death from my functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function, passwords

I'm creating a wordpress theme from scratch and using the following in my wordpress functions.php file to be able to style protected posts.

The code, taken from here – [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-and-styling-the-password-protected-form--wp-22375)

However the code is giving my a white screen each time I try to login to the backend or update posts. Any advice on what I could be missing here would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<div id="protected">
        <form class="protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post">

    <div class="padlock"></div>
    ' . __( "You'll need a password to get in here" ) . '
    <label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( "PASSWORD:" ) . ' </label><input class="post_password" name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" placeholder="Password"/><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form></div>
    ';
    return $o;
}
?>
```

**EDIT — After removing the theme and playing around, the error is definitely in this .functions.php file, I'm just unsure where**

Comment: A white screen of death means you need to turn on debugging (either at the PHP level, or at the WordPress level). Verbose output of errors will help immensely.

Comment: please activate debugging: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress lots of places an error might come from. After a qick view I see you have a ' character unescaped in "You'll need a password" that I think breaks your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no empty lines before opening  from the functions.php.